# SVE / SVE2 support in GNU toolchain

Tags: sve

I want to write an SVE/SVE2 code (assembly and/or C intrinsic) code. Which version of GNU supports SVE / SVE2? I am also interested in auto-vectorization if that is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVE assembly/disassembly/auto-vectorization is supported in GCC 8.x onwards. SVE C intrinsics (also known as ACLE) is supported in GCC 10.x.

SVE2 assembly/disassembly/auto-vectorization/C-intrinsics is supported in GCC10.x onwards.

For full details, visit https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/sve-support

Answer (score 1):

[LLVM toolchain SVE Support Messages](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/llvm-toolchain/sve-support) and  [GNU Toolchain Messages](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/sve-support).

Comment: Thanks. I have now updated the link to my original answer as well.